# Javascript / ASP.NET asp:Label (span) doesn't exist in DOM according to getElementById

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am using `PageMethods` to execute codebehind logic from javascript without causing a postback. My js works fine initially calling the method in codebehind as well as returning result properly. However when my `OnSuccess()` function is called I use `document.getElementById(elementId)` it fails to find the element in the DOM. I've looked around many posts on here and they may help except I haven't found anyone that is actually trying to find dynamically generated elements in their page. I will explain further:

I have a dropdown that has a list of items, for each one of these items there is a number of fields that describe the item. These fields are random and are dynamically loaded into the page when the SelectedIndex of the DropDownList Changes. I do this using a `<asp:Repeater>` control databound to an Object[] of items. I bind my js function `GetDigitData(this)` to the oninput="" attribute of the Dynamic textboxes generated during the DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged databinding event.

**ASPX Content Page**

```
<asp:Content ID="PCBody" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/configurator.js"></script>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="PCUPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/configurator.js"></script>
            <h2 id="pc_head">Product Configurator</h2>
            <section id="pc_controls">
                <asp:DropDownList
                    ID="ModelDropdown"
                    runat="server"
                    DataSourceID="ModelDataSource"
                    DataTextField="Model"
                    DataValueField="Model"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="ModelDropdown_SelectedIndexChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="true"/>
                <asp:SqlDataSource
                    ID="ModelDataSource"
                    runat="server"
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DepotData %>"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Model] FROM [tbl_BSP_Configurator] ORDER BY [Model] ASC;"/>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="GetDataButton" runat="server" Text="Get Data" OnClick="GetDataButton_Click" />
            </section>
            <br />
            <section id="pc_display">
                <section id="pc_digits">
                    <asp:Repeater
                        ID="ControlRepeater"
                        runat="server">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <section class="heady-repeater">
                                <table class="heady-repeater-table">
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="DigitTextBox" runat="server" placeholder='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>' Width="50px" oninput="GetDigitData(this)"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="TypeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Type") %>' />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" placeholder='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID") %>' Text="Enter Digit And Click Get Data"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                                </table>
                            </section>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </section>
            </section>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

**JS:**

```
function GetDigitData(element) {
    var dest = "MainContent_ControlRepeater_DescriptionLabel_" +
        element.id.substring(element.id.length - 1, element.id.length);
    var position = element.getAttribute("placeholder");
    var content = element.value;
    window.PageMethods.RetrieveDescription(dest, position, content, OnSuccess, OnFailure);
}

function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response[0]);
    alert(response[1]);
    var label = document.getElementById(response[0]);
    alert(label.name);
    label.value = response[1];
}

function OnFailure(response) {
    alert(response.get_message());
}
```

I've validated that my `GetDigitData()` function returns successfully using the alert() function, I get the data I should back from the `PageMethod.RetrieveDescription()` method. But once my OnSuccess() function is called it is as if the element I'm looking for (in this case the one that corresponds with the TextBox that originally called the `GetDigitData()` function oninput, doesn't exist in the DOM. This is weird, it should exist in the DOM if the original element that called the `GetDigitData()` function exists in the DOM right?

I've tried using jQuery I just cannot seem to get it to work right with the ScriptManager, everything jQuery just stays undefined even though it's included in my ScriptBundle.... My methodology should work, however I'm not familiar enough with JS atm to be of much use debugging what exists in the DOM and why. Any ideas how I can determine what's in the DOM or why I can't find my element by it's ID in the DOM?

Comment: What does the data in reponse[0] and response[1] look like in the alert messages?  My gut feeling is that you're missing a '#' or '.' in front of the element name

Comment: Ahhh damn, I am not currently including a # in front of the element name! I'll try that when I've fixed this SQL server issue that popped up, I'm the only one in the office today unfortunately

Comment: Also if you look at the ` dest ` that's the id of the element I will be targeting in OnSuccess